# Using loops to allow me to enter several numbers into a console application program, and then do calculations

Tags: vb.net

This is basically the details of my assignment

> Using loops, write a visual basic console application will allow you to enter an arbitrary amount of numbers. The application should then calculate the average of all the numbers entered by the user. Input should be validated using loops to ensure the data entered is a valid number. If an entered value is not valid, the user should be prompted until they enter a valid number.
>
> Output the following to the Console
>
> Sum of the Numbers Entered:
>
> Total Number of Numbers Entered:
>
> Average of Numbers Entered:

The way I am thinking about doing it is:

- Have the user prompt for a number
- check to see if it's numeric or not
- if its not numeric it prompts again
- if it is numeric, it prompts for more numbers
- have an option where a user can type a key or keyword, and the program stops collecting numbers, and does the calculations, outputting the following three things that were required.

My issue is that I can't really visualize on how to do it, or really how to write it in such a way. My initial issue with learning so far is not being able to see how it works, or an example of the code, but when I do - I can understand it and use it efficiently. I just have trouble visualizing how to do/write it.

```
Dim str_num As String
Dim int_num As Integer
Dim int_counter As Integer

Sub Main()
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.Clear()

    Do
        Console.WriteLine("enter a number") 'prompts user to enter a number, followed by it storing in a variable.
        str_num = Console.ReadLine

        If Not IsNumeric(str_num) Then
            int_num = str_num
            Console.ReadKey()

        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can change you `Do ... Loop` to `Do ... Loop Until <input = youKeyWord>` so you now have a stop condition. As for inside the loop, your valid numbers can be added to a list and you'd do nothing with the non numbers (strings). If you string is equal to your keyword, it exits. If not it prompts the user again. Once the loop is exited you can get the sum, total and average from the list.

Comment: Can I see an example? I'm a visual learner.

Comment: If the problem is too complicated, break it down! For example, you could write a function whose sole purpose is to read from the console and attempt to parse it as

Comment: Since arrays are a set size, as stated above, you would store the numbers into a list. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888109/how-to-append-an-integer-to-an-array-in-visual-basic?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim num As Integer
    'With a list, unlike an array, we don't have to know beforehand how many items we are going to add.
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number.")
        'A nested Do will test for a proper number
        Do
            'Integer.TryParse will return true if a valid number was entered and fill in the 
            'num variable with that number
            If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, num) Then
                'Since we have a valid number we add it to the lst
                lst.Add(num)
                'and exit the inner Do
                Exit Do
            Else
                'If it isn't valid, we ask again for an input, the inner loop continues until we get a valid input
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid number. Please try again")
            End If
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("Is that enough numbers? Yes, No")
        'Call .ToUpper on the input so we don't have to depend on what case the user typed in
        If Console.ReadLine.ToUpper = "YES" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    'We can use the .Sum method and .Average method of the list to do the calculaion
    Dim sumNum = lst.Sum()
    'I have used Interpolated strings indicated by the $. These allow you to insert a variable 
    'surrounded by braces {} directly into a string.
    'In Visual Studio prior to version 2015
    'use Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The sum of the numbers you entered is {0}", sumNum))
    Console.WriteLine($"The sum of the numbers you entered is {sumNum}")
    Dim avgNum = lst.Average()
    Console.WriteLine($"The average of the numbers your entered is {avgNum}")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You look like you want to code it yourself, but miss a couple resources. I'll give you resources. You'll implement the logic. Deal?

Here's a way to get an input from the user and verify if it's really a number:

```
    Dim userInput As String
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:")
    userInput = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim inputAsInteger As Integer = 0
    If Not Int32.TryParse(userInput, inputAsInteger) Then 'TryParse returns a Boolean which reads True if it worked 
        Console.WriteLine("Hey, that wasn't a number!")
    End If
```

Here's a loop logic which you can use to gather your inputs:

```
    Dim stopLooping As Boolean = False
    Dim i As Integer = 0 'I'll count the loops with this integer, but the exit condition can be anything

    Do
        'Some code which do your stuff

        'At some point, a condifion can flip stopLooping to True when you want the loop to stop
        Console.WriteLine("Loop number " & i.ToString)
        If i > 10 Then
            stopLooping = True
        End If
    Loop Until stopLooping
```

Now you should be able to figure out something out of these tools, right? I'm sure you will. Have fun!

Comment: I still can't. I'm really having a hard time with loops, unfortunately. I'm less than two months into this course, and we literally just started our loops module today. I'm so frustrated that I can't understand/grasp this concept.

Comment: Or well I understand a very basic concept of a loop, basically how to take the number from a variable and increment it by however many numbers, but beyond that, I get really confused and frustrated.

Comment: You are on the right track when you write down what you want the code to do step by step. That's basically pseudocode. A lot of students underestimate pseudocode by a huge margin. You can write "easy" stuff right off the bat, but anything complex deserves pseudocode, even if it's not detailed.

Comment: @SilasLeFriend You can improve your loop (the one you posted) by setting an exit condition (for an example, it can be when the user types the "special stop word"). Then try your loop again to see if it works. Working by gradual improvements is a good way to make sure that everything works as you intend it.

Comment: Yes, that's a good start. There's a lot to improve upon, but you'll get that in time. Now, declare a variable out of the loop so you can sum the user's inputs, and implement it. Hint: every time the `TryParse` says that it's a number... add it up.

Comment: I still can't/don't really understand, sorry. Rough going right now with this stuff. Can you just show me the completed code with comments? I think it would be the best way for me to understand. If I can see it and see how it works, then I can absorb it. Sorry.